# Unicode active text character, to macro

Tags: fontspec

This works, but it is frightening... Is it reliable, or am I exploiting something that will not be there in the future? Using TeXlive 2024, LuaLaTeX, any platform (mine is Linux). Tex mode only, no complications with math, tables, diagrams.

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\catcode`\ﬀ=13
\defﬀ{AB}
\begin{document}
yﬀr
\end{document}
```

Result: `yABr` as expected.

What I did was define `ﬀ` as an active character (it is Unicode FB00), then defined it as a macro. Of course, my actual usage is more complex.

The above seems to work with a variety of possible Unicode characters. I would not expect (or need) it to work with most of them. Also, I would only use characters that are known to be in the fonts I use.

My question, again: Is that reliable?

Comment: Sure, that is not different to other active chars like ~ and it doesn't matter if the char is in a font, that is input not output

Comment: Define `reliable` ;).

Comment: In the current context, it precludes `ﬀ` from producing ﬀ in the output.  There are other possible complications, if parsing or comparing input containing `ﬀ`, if not done in the proper way.

Comment: This is more or less what the `newunicodechar` package does, it defines ``\def\newunicodechar#1#2{ ... \catcode`#1=\active \begingroup\lccode`\~=`#1 \lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{#2} ... }``.

Comment: @cfr reliable: Like me. When I lie, I lie again. So I am re-lie-able.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Indeed. In use, I would choose characters that should never appear in the output (my usage does not need a vast number of characters).

Comment: What I meant is: there's 'reliable' in the sense of the code itself won't break. TeX won't change what the code does. There's also 'reliable' in the sense of being relatively robust given the vagaries of human input. May I ask why you want to do this? On the face of it, it seems odd to want to substitute something (presumably) harder to input for something easier. And of course it is rather lacking in transparency and will make code less readable.

Comment: @cfr I use text only, and sometimes must exchange plain-text writing (not TeX code) with an editor who will probably open it in a word processor. I am not certain whether some glyphs are automatically changed there (such as two f going to the double-f glyph). I would never type it myself. So, I want to trap it, if it shows up on the returned text file.

Comment: @rallg That sounds like something to script rather than something you'd use a macro for to catch during typesetting, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite reliable, but not completely. And it ***requires*** a Unicode engine, either `xetex` or `luatex`.

For instance, if you have `\section{ﬀ}`, in the `.toc` file you'll see `AB`, which might not be what you want.

Besides, you cannot define `ﬀ` in terms of itself. A common usage of `newunicodechar` is for substituting fonts for (typically) symbols that aren't present in the main font. Say your favorite font has no glyph for `☯`, but you have it in Symbola.

Then you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontface{\symbola}{Symbola}

\newunicodechar{☯}{{\normalfont\symbola ☯}}

\begin{document}

\section{Yin Yang ☯}

☯ is a nice glyph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't try

```
\catcode`☯=\active
\def ☯{{\normalfont\symbola ☯}}
```

or, maybe, try it, just to discover

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again>
                   {
l.16 \section{Yin Yang ☯}
```

However, it mostly depend on what you want to do. I cannot recommend taking a random unused Unicode character and define it to be active and to do some action not related to the character itself. It may appear funny and maybe useful: it isn't.

---

Why does it work with `\newunicodechar`? Because the code has

```
\def\newunicodechar#1#2{...}
```

so the second argument is tokenized before the definition of `#1` as an active character is performed, so in the code passed as `#2` the character would have its normal category code.

By the way, the package also works with `pdflatex`, but you can't use the character in the replacement text, in this case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you input the symbol? (OK. Not just curiosity, but that, too. I'd like to be able to input a pound sign without first compiling a document to create a symbol to copy-paste. I often leave it out.)

Comment: @cfr I use UnicodeChecker on macOS, that allows search for character descriptions; once the character is found, it tells what system fonts provide it. If I also want the fonts in the TeX Live tree, I can copy the character and use `albatross`. We might lobby for adding support of search for character descriptions also in `albatross`.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to `albatross`. Too bad it doesn't support searching for descriptions itself.

Comment: @cfr I asked Paulo to add the feature, he said he'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks! He could search for `duck` if he does ;).

Comment: @cfr I input it by copy-paste, since I use only utf-8, and have a good app for the character map. I suppose there is a LaTeX macro for the double-f, but I would not use it.

Comment: @rallg The double-f has no macro. It is handled by the font configuration. Why do you want to remove it from your source? I guess it makes searching your source easier and, of course, if it is getting substituted in code listings, that's different. Otherwise, why does it matter?

Comment: @cfr It may or may not matter. However, in my very specific usage, my own code handles  two consecutive `f` in a way that is not the usual. If the editor's software inserts the double-f character, I want to trap it. Instead of `AB` as used in my MWE, I would simply decompose the dobule-f into two f. Then it could be handled by my other macros. This is not for everyone. I also wish to use an obscure (for me) character as a temporary holding pattern for something else. Understand that I do no math, no tables, no diagrams, and no `aux` file.

Comment: @rallg Just curious, but do you mean that you deliberately prevent some ligatures? That has nothing to do with maths, tables, diagrams or any generated file.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I deliberately prevent some ligatures. This is very usage-dependent, and has to do with the fact that I exchange plain-text files with a TeX-unaware editor who uses a word processor. Not relevant to 99.9 percent of TeX users. Also know that I use a custom font that does not need ligatures. Alternative to what I asked, is screening files via BASH script (outside of TeX), which is what I have been doing previously.

Comment: @rallg You're saying that your word processor changes `ff` into `ﬀ` instead of just relying on OpenType font features?

Comment: @egreg It is not my word processor. It is a human (probably a trainee) at a word processor. Not within my control. The human does unexpected things with the software. I am not important enough to get high-end editors. :(

Comment: That's the input, though. I'm curious why you want to prevent them in the output. (If that's what you're doing.)

Comment: @cfr Actaully, I intend to decompose `ﬀ` into `ff` (on Unicode character, to two), then use `liga` feature to recompose to `f_f` (in the font, but not a Unicode point). Advantages: Easy to turn `liga` on or off, locally. Also, if plain text is extracted from the PDF, `f_f` will be seen as `ff` (two characters). Also spell-check implications. None of this would be necessary if I did not exchange files.

Comment: `f_f` is just the name some fonts use for the ligature as far as I know. (Only some - unfortunately there's no standard naming scheme.) I don't know LuaTeX well enough but it's surprising if copy/search of the PDF depends on not having the ligature in the input.

Answer (score 3):

With lualatex unicode input like `ﬀ` or `ü` or  are input characters and not different to `a` or `~`. So you can make them active and give them a definition. That will always work regardless of fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\=13
\def{duck}

 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That gives me ideas.

Answer (score 3):

How to do the same output like presented in egreg's answer, but using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]            % default font family
\sfont\symbola=Symbola  % \symbola is font scaled by the context
\adef ☯{{\symbola ☯}}   % the character ☯ is active, defined by non-active ☯

\sec Yin Yang ☯

☯ is a nice glyph.

\bye
```

Comment: Although I do not use OpTeX, your answer is valuable, because other users may find it.